# Problema com Buscador PHP

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

BOA TARDE GALERA

estou desenvolvendo um site para um cliente e ele deseja colocar um localizador (pesquisa), no caso colocar o nome da pessoa e aparecer o local de sepultamento dela.

so que eu fiz o código php e o banco de dados, porem quando eu faço o teste, aparece o resultado em branco.

aparece assim para mim:

```
Cemiterio Municipal Parque Águas Lindas
Localizador de Jazigos
Resultado da Pesquisa:
Resultado da Pesquisa:
Resultado da Pesquisa:
Resultado da Pesquisa:
Resultado da Pesquisa:
```

e no caso era para aparecer assim:

```
Cemiterio Municipal Parque Águas Lindas
Localizador de Jazigos
Resultado da Pesquisa:maria claudia
Resultado da Pesquisa:maria cunha
Resultado da Pesquisa:maria lina
Resultado da Pesquisa:maria da luz
Resultado da Pesquisa:maria costa
```

o código do formulário e esse que eu fiz:

```
<h1><center>Cemiterio Municipal Parque Águas Lindas</center></h1>
<h1><center>Localizador de Jazigos</center></h1>

<form method="POST" action="pesquisar.php">
    <center> Pesquisar:<input type="text" name="pesquisar" placeholder="Nome do Falecido">
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR"></center>
</form>
```

e o codigo da pesquisa e esse:

```
<h1><center>Cemiterio Municipal Parque Águas Lindas</center></h1>
<h1><center>Localizador de Jazigos</center></h1>
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "EU NAO POSTEI A SENHA";
    $database = "cemiterio";
    //Criar a conexao
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);

    $pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5";
    $resultado_cemiterio = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);

    while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio)){
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:" ."<br>";
    }
?>
```

PRECISO MUITO DE AJUDA COM ESSE PROJETO

E aproveitando, preciso que o resultado apresente toda as informaçoes da linha do nome pesquisado ( a tabela tem 8 colunas) tipo pesquisa "maria lima"
ai aparece assim:

```
mome :maria lina Data de nascimento: 10/10/190  idade: 80 anos 
 Data de falecimento: 01/10/2018 Quadra: 03 Jazigo: 1250 Gaveta: 03
```

ja nao sei mais oq fazer, fiz muita pesquisa, mais nao encontrei uma solução

deste ja agradeço a sua atenção e colaboração.

Comment: Posta o código para olharmos, senão ficará impossível de te ajudar.

Comment: Vc quer apenas fazer uma pesquisa simples por um texto digitado no formulário.

Comment: 'echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:" ."<br>";' você tem um problema de lógica aqui, deveria ter algo do tipo: `echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:" . $rows_sql['col1'] . "<br>"`

Answer (score -1):

No caso você realmente está conseguindo fazer a pesquisa e ela está lhe retornando os resultados, o que está faltando é você exibi-los. Dentro do loop `while` substitua por esse:

```
 while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["nome_da_coluna_da_sua_tabela"]  ."<br>";
    }
```

Troque a query por essa:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 5";
```

Você está esquecendo de exibir o resultado através dos índices da sua tabela no `array` retornado

Comment: cara, deu certo

Comment: voce pode mim tira mais uma duvida?

Comment: @KaduSilva Sim, pois não.

Comment: essa minha tabela ela tem 8 colunas assim:

nome -data de nascimento-idade-data de falecimento- quadra-jazigo-gaveta


o cliente quer que quando eu coloque o nome da pessoa apareca os resultados da linha

Comment: porque agora so mostra o nome da pessoa

Comment: @KaduSilva para você conseguir listar as 8 colunas basta você na linha de baixo, fazer o mesmo procedimento porém só alterando o o nome das colunas, como por exemplo:`echo "<br/>".$rows_sql["coluna_x"]." <br/>".$rows_sql["coluna_y"]` e assim por diante.

Comment: ai mostra o dado da linha do nome da pessoa

Comment: mais em qual ponto eu coloco isso?

Comment: @KaduSilva é só ir acrescentando na mesma linha, por exemplo: `echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:".$rows_sql["coluna_x"]."<br/>".$rows_sql["coluna_y"]."<br/>".$rows_sql["coluna_z"];`

Comment: vou testar
desculpa a demora, sair do cemiterio, cheguei em casa agora a pouco e agora que vim para o escritorio

Comment: no caso seria assim:

Comment: <?php
 $servidor = "localhost";
 $usuario = "root";
 $senha = "201620682";
 $database = "cemiterio";
 //Criar a conexao
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);
 
 $pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 25";
 $resultado_cemiterio = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);
 
  while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["NOME"]  ."<br>";
   echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["DATA_DE_NASCIMENTO"]  ."<br>";

    }
?>

Answer (score -1):

Seu resultado está em branco porque você não está escrevendo os dados no `echo`

```
while ($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio)) {
    //Aqui você escrever apenas um HTML fixo, não tem os dados do banco
    echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:" ."<br>";
}
```

O que você quer é algo assim:

```
echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:<br>";
while ($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio)) {
    echo implode(", ", $rows_sql)."<br>";
}
```

Nesse exemplo simples eu apenas uni as colunas do resultado com uma vírgula mas você pode arrumar como preferir pegando cada coluna separadamente através dos índices, de uma olhada na [documentação do `mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Observação:

- Do modo como está seu código está vulnerável a [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/)
- Se por acaso não for enviada uma variável `pesquisar` pelo corpo da requisição, o código irá quebrar, seria necessário usar algo como `$pesquisar = isset($_POST['pesquisar']) ? $_POST['pesquisar']; : ''` ou `$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar']; ?? ''` (PHP 7)